# How to clear local nottification when app is killed from backgroud

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to clear local notification when app is closed by swiped from background.
I tried with isAppIsInBackground method but it not works. 
below is my code :-

```
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod  do you have any solution about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For check whether your app is run in backround,do as following step.

Firstly,Make sure you have a class XXApplication which extends class android.app.Application,if not then create one.

Secondly,create a class LifeCycleCallback

```
class LifeCycleCallback implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   }
   @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
   @Override
   public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
       isBackground = false;           
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
       isBackground = true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

   }
}
```

Thirdly,add a variable `isBackground` in XXApplication class

Finally,in XXApplication invoke `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LifeCycleCallback());`

Well,now you can judge whether your app is in background by variable `isBackground`.

Any question please contact me.

Comment: But the situation is if user remove the application from recent then my notification also be remove same as music player.

Comment: oh,You can't stop that in that situation case it is removed by Android system,you can't disturb it.